# Customizing AutoFixture builder with seeded property

Tags: c#, autofixture

I've got a customized autofixture builder for an integration test.  Code is below.

Question 1 - At present the first transaction has a TransactionViewKey.TransactionId of 1, etc.  How do I set the TransactionViewKey TransactionId so it is seeded from the method param *beginningTransactionId*?  eg returning an array of TransactionViews where the first TransactionId is 200, then each incrementing by 1?

Question 2 - the lambda for determining transactiondate seems to be run once only - and so each date is the same value.  How do I setup the builder so it runs the random date generator for each generated instance rather than once only?

thanks

```
  static TransactionView[] CreateTransactions(int transactionsToReturnCount, long beginningTransactionId) {
      Random random = new Random();
      IFixture fixture = new Fixture();
      fixture.Customize<TransactionViewKey>(ob => ob
                                    .With(t => t.TransactionId)
                                    .With(t => t.TransactionIdSpecified, true)
                                    .OmitAutoProperties()
                                    );
      fixture.Customize<TransactionView>(ob => ob
                                             .With(t => t.TransactionDate, DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(random.Next(30),0,0,0))
                                             .With(t => t.PostDate, DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(random.Next(30), 0, 0, 0))
                                             .With(t => t.ViewKey)
                                             .With(t => t.Amount)
                                             .OmitAutoProperties()
          );
      IEnumerable<TransactionView> transactionViews = fixture.CreateMany<TransactionView>(transactionsToReturnCount);
      return transactionViews.OrderBy(t => t.TransactionDate).ToArray();
  }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Before I dive into answering the specific questions, I'd like to point out something that might be a lot easier: you *might* consider just assigning values to those writable properties after you called CreateMany, but before you return the result.

Something like this:

```
var transactionViews = fixture.CreateMany<TransactionView>(transactionsToReturnCount);
foreach (var tv in transactionViews)
{
    tv.ViewKey.TransactionId = beginningTransactionId++;
    tv.TransactionDate = DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(random.Next(30),0,0,0);
}
return transactionViews.OrderBy(t => t.TransactionDate).ToArray();
```

This might look like a hack, but really isn't. AutoFixture is designed to create [Anonymous Values](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2008/11/17/anonymous-variables.aspx) so whenever you are trying to assign specific values (which you currently are), you are stepping outside of its original purpose.

Don't get me wrong: it's cool that you use AutoFixture like this. I also sometimes have to assign some specific values to some members of the specimens I have AutoFixture create, but I tend to use the above technique, because the normal .NET API of getters and setter is **already specialized at doing exactly that**. AutoFixture, on the other hand, is specialized at defining rules for being vague, so its purpose is the opposite.

That said, however, I will now answer the specific questions put forth above:

**Question 1**

I haven't tried to compile this, so you may have to tweak it a bit, but the best thing you can do would be something like this:

```
fixture.Customize<TransactionViewKey>(ob => ob
    .Without(t => t.TransactionId)
    .Do(t => t.TransactionId = beginningTransactionId++)
    .With(t => t.TransactionIdSpecified, true)
    .OmitAutoProperties());
```

**Question 2**

The second parameter to the With method is *not* a delegate - it's a *value* so it's only being evaluated once.

To evaluate it each time, you can use the same trick as above:

```
fixture.Customize<TransactionView>(ob => ob
    .Without(t => t.TransactionDate)
    .Do(t => t.TransactionDate = DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(random.Next(30),0,0,0))
    .With(t => t.PostDate, DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(random.Next(30), 0, 0, 0))
    .With(t => t.ViewKey)
    .With(t => t.Amount)
    .OmitAutoProperties());
```

Please let me know if you have any additional questions.

HTH

Comment: excellent, makes sense - thanks heaps.  i hadn't realised that Do is essentially run per object build.
getting lots of good use out of autofixture - just wish i had found it earlier.