# Is AutoFixture generating 2 different lists?

Tags: c#, autofixture

I'm new to AutoFixture and quickly testing out its features but I'm running into a bit of a snag. Below is my test:

```
// Arrange
Fixture.Register(() => Fixture.CreateMany<SyncItemChange>(10));
var syncFolderItemsResult = Fixture.CreateAnonymous<SyncFolderItemsResult>();
ExchangeWebServiceMock
    .Setup(x => x.Sync())
    .Returns(() => syncFolderItemsResult);

// Act
Listener.Begin();

// Assert
var expectedItemIdsToBind = syncFolderItemsResult
    .ItemChanges
    .Select(x => x.ItemId);
ExchangeWebServiceMock.Verify(x => x.BindToItems(expectedItemIdsToBind), Times.Once());
```

Nothing fancy. The issue I'm running into is that when I first create an anonymous instance of `SyncFolderItemsResult`, the `SyncItemsChanges` aren't the same from the time I create it to the time I assert that I'm binding the proper `ItemId`'s. Thus, making the test fail.

Why am I generating 2 different lists?

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181865/autofixture-ienumerablet-behavior-with-creatmany/6183359#6183359

Comment: That fixed the issue, thank you. If you want to add that as your answer I will gladly accept it. :D