# How do I assign a property on only a subrange of items in a list?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, autofixture

I want to create a list of custom objects using `AutoFixture`. I want the first `N` objects to have a property set to one value, and the remainder to have it set to another value (or to simply be set by the `Fixture`'s default strategy).

I am aware that I can use `Fixture.CreateMany<T>.With`, but this applies a function to *all* members of the list.

In `NBuilder` there are methods named `TheFirst` and `TheNext` (among others) which provide this functionality. An example of their use:

Given a class `Foo`:

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar {get; set;}
    public int Blub {get; set;}
}
```

one can instantiate a bunch of `Foo`s like so:

```
class TestSomethingUsingFoo
{
    /// ... set up etc.

    [Test]
    public static void TestTheFooUser()
    {
        var foosToSupplyToTheSUT = Builder<Foo>.CreateListOfSize(10)
            .TheFirst(5)
                .With(foo => foo.Bar = "Baz")
            .TheNext(3)
                .With(foo => foo.Bar = "Qux")
            .All()
                .With(foo => foo.Blub = 11)
            .Build();

        /// ... perform the test on the SUT 
    }
}
```

This gives a list of objects of type `Foo` with the following properties:

```
[Object]    Foo.Bar    Foo.Blub
--------------------------------
0           Baz        10
1           Baz        10
2           Baz        10
3           Baz        10
4           Baz        10
5           Qux        10
6           Qux        10
7           Qux        10
8           Bar9       10
9           Bar10      10
```

(The `Bar9` and `Bar10` values represent `NBuilder`'s default naming scheme)

Is there a 'built-in' way to achieve this using `AutoFixture`? Or an idiomatic way to set up a fixture to behave like this?

Comment: What does the `Foo` class look like?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I've expanded the example using the `Foo` to make it a bit clearer. If you meant the actual class in my real-life project for which `Foo` is a proxy, it's much the same: just a POCO with gettable/settable `string`, `int`, `DateTime` fields.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By far the easiest way to do that would be like this:

```
var foos = fixture.CreateMany<Foo>(10).ToList();
foos.Take(5).ToList().ForEach(f => f.Bar = "Baz");
foos.Skip(5).Take(3).ToList().ForEach(f => f.Bar = "Qux");
foos.ForEach(f => f.Blub = 11);
```

Assigning values to properties is already built-in to C#, so instead of providing a restrictive API that can't possibly enable you to do everything you'd want to do, [the AutoFixture philosophy is to use the language constructs already available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398653/126014).

The next philosophical step is that if you *often* need to do something like that, the [SUT](http://xunitpatterns.com/SUT.html) could probably benefit from a redesign.

Comment: Yes, that was the strategy I ended up using. I realise from the discussion at your link that this use case diverges from the core intention of AutoFixture. I just got used to NBuilder's delicious syntactic sugar... sugar which I suspect I can implement myself on top of `IEnumerable<T>` if I really want that 'fluent' feel to my code.

Comment: Neat solution. IMHO, I still think it would be nice if this was built in.